# Script for automatic commit and increase of build number

Tags: git, bash

I want to automatically make a new commit with an increased build number after each successful build.

I use this un-tracked, self-modifying script:

```
let N=`tail -n 1 $0`+1
sed -i '' "5s/.*/$N/" $0
echo $N
exit 0
0
```

On each invocation it increases the number on the last line and echoes it, and as part of my makefile I commit like this:

```
git commit -m "build `sh script.sh`"
```

Is there a better and more elegant solution to this? What are some of the problems that may arise with my solution?

EDIT:

Thanks for the comments. I've over-thought this a bit, and will look at the other methods suggested.

Comment: It looks like you use this whenever you want to issue a "release"? What about using `git tag` to add tags when you want to release. Then, simply include the tag version in your commit message as the release (this can be done via a script as well)

Comment: interesting solution, I would suggest not hard coding the line number for sed since it may overwrite one of the script lines with later modifications. `sed '$s/.*/'"$N"'/'` would do.

Comment: Or do the commit at every build, but only update the ref it the build succeeds.  Then you can use `git describe` output. in the build.

Comment: You might want a version like  `(Major version).(Minor version).(Revision number).(Build number)` or at least  `(Major version).(Minor version)`.
Committing unchanged code will cause additional work for dependant projects and looking for the version/file/date that has caused a production problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to keep the build in it's own text file and have your script for maintaining the file remain constant rather than change it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Initialize build.txt if it doesn't exist
if [[ ! -f build.txt ]]; then
    echo 0 >> build.txt
fi
let build=$(cat build.txt)+1
echo $build > build.txt
echo $build
```

Reasons to not write self modifying code? It's harder to reason about, it looks like the fact it's self modifying is discouraging you from checking it in. Also in my experience a bug can end up with the script being reduced to an empty file. [See also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code#Disadvantages).

That said, I think you should be leveraging something like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) which will manage the build numbers for you. It doesn't make commits tracking successful builds but the interface will show you successful and unsuccessful builds.

I am against making commits automatically in general, and certainly in this case your version history will become cluttered making it impossible to see real changes. Again, a tool like Jenkins will make this information available to you in a more appropriate manner, and it's what I would expect to find in place.

Answer (score 2):

If you tag your releases (which is a good idea anyway) you can just use `git describe --tags` to generate a build number.

An example from one of my own repositories;

```
> git describe --tags
1.10-99-g6928bd0
```

This means that after the tag `1.10`, 99 commits have been done. The short commit-id for HEAD is `6928bd0`.

If you don't want the HEAD, you can do something like;

```
> git describe --tags | awk -F '-' 'BEGIN {OFS="-"} {print $1, $2}'
1.10-99
```